# How to query a Django ManyToMany field from the other side

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Let's say we have two models in our Django app:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Normally, for a many to many field I would make an intermediary table and just query that:

```
class BookAuthor(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

Since then I can simply query BookAuthor by either `book` or `author`.

However, the django `ManyToManyField` would change this to:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

So now I can query a book's authors......but what about the other way round - an Author's books?

Comment: You just define `related_name` attr on `ManyToManyField` field. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the author's books like this:

```
author.book_set.all()
```

Note that the default is different in a query, you just use the model name:

```
Author.objects.filter(book__name__startswith="The")
```

You can override both of these defaults by setting the `related_name` and `related_query_name` attributes on your M2M field. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).